# Is it safe to use a power adapter with a hard disk which has output current 60% of the startup current required by hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, power

When I was checking my external hdd Buffalo HD-LX2TU3, I found the startup current of Seagate ST2000DM001 (aka Barracuda or Desktop HDD) in it is 2.5A and output current of the adapter comes with Buffalo HD-LX2TU3 is 1.5A. The hard disk requires 67% higher than the adapter could offer.

Is it safe use of electricity usage and safe to my hard disk?

Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. I collect all related information for this issue on [Match Hard Disk Startup Current with Power Adapter Output Current](http://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2013/12/31/match-hard-disk-startup-current-with-power-adapter-output-current) and will update in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spend several weeks and finally get my conclusion with the help of web, forums, and papers.

Here is a list of the **relationship between inrush current and power adapter**.

1. Adapter is responsible for steady voltage within its designed capacity (watt).
2. Inrush current will lower voltage and increase temperature suddenly.
3. High temperature is bad to capacitor.
4. Low than minim voltage will shutdown the component.
5. Most adapter only provide guarantee current which is different from inrush current.
6. Most vendor didn't provide inrush current information.
7. Inrush current has its limit which can be calculated by formula:
   capacitor inrush current = 1.44 √(short circuit current * normal capacitor Rated Current)
8. "The high inrush currents can cause damage to the capacitors of the capacitors bank and to weld the contacts of the switch together" according to S.J. Kulas
9. Capacitor is used to make sure there is steady voltage.

**My conclusion**: Inrush current is bad to power adapter. It is a better to shorten the gap of inrush current and output current to help capacitor live longer. If there is huge gap between them, inrush current generate much more heat than usual which will shorten the capacitor life and your  power adapter might not be able to provide steady voltage

If the power adapter becomes unstable, it is dangerous.

Detail information are explained in [Match Hard Disk Startup Current with Power Adapter Output Current](http://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2013/12/31/match-hard-disk-startup-current-with-power-adapter-output-current). The reference sections provides many useful links and helps me to know more about electricity.

**Finally**, the answer to my questions is yes for now if the vendor have stress test during QC.

After warranty period, I better get another new adapter because the original adapter is not designed to work after the warranty period. It might already be aging due to high temperature by inrush current and fail to provide steady voltage.